# How to make this slider auto slide?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am using [responsiveslidercss3](http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/index.html) slider in One of my website. But you can see that this slider has no auto sliding options means slider is not automatic sliding. To slide you have to click on one of the arrow or button. I want to make it auto slide. So can some one help me here?

Comment: Hi @amit patel used to this http://bxslider.com/ now you created all slider

Comment: I want to use this one. So can some one help me then pls guide me

Answer (score 0):

Responsive CSS3 Slider **Without Javascript**

Find a different slider. Autoslide requires javascript, it can't be done with CSS alone.

Comment: Downvote for telling him autoslide isn't possible without JS? Seriously?